# Scanner issues in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

What is wrong with my scanner?  I tried to not put it in a loop either, and it was not working.  I want the user to enter a choice and then the server to be printed out along with choice?

```
private static String getLogLocation(){
    System.out.print("Please pick one (Dev, UAT, Lab, Sandbox): ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String server = null;
    Boolean breaking = true;
    String choice = scan.nextLine();

    while(scan.hasNext() && breaking){
        if(choice.equals("Dev")){
            server = "CNNDCPV02465.dcld.nndc.kp.org";
            breaking = false;
        }
        if(choice.equals("UAT")){
            server = "CNNDCPV02464.dcld.nndc.kp.org";
            breaking = false;
        }
        if(choice.equals("Lab")){
            server = "CNNDCBIPP242.nndc.kp.org";
            breaking = false;
        }
        if(choice.equals("Sandbox")){
            server = "CNNDCBIPP241.nndc.kp.org";
            breaking = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Server" + server);
    return server;
}
```

Comment: "it was not working" how it is not working? I suspect that it is working fine (just not the way you want).

Comment: @Pshemo I enter an input and then nothing happens? even if I hit enter a few times.

Comment: Your loop is not a loop (uncondition `break` at end). Your code does nothing with the `server` value. As-is, user presses enter and code exits.

Comment: I got rid of the loop and still nothing is going into the conditional statements @Andreas

Comment: How would you know? You never use the `server` value.

Comment: so I do need a loop and I can just check if server equals any of those values?

Comment: insert System.out.println(server); to see server value

Comment: No. You have two variables: `logLoc` and `server`. `logLoc` is initialized the `""` and it used as method return value, so method *always* returns `""`. If statements assign a value to `server`, but is never used for anything.

Comment: **FYI:** Don't call `scan.close()` on a Scanner using `System.in`.

Comment: @Andreas why ? Isnt it releases input stream then close itself

Comment: Still believe I have an infinite loop going on? Nothing is being printed.

Comment: You dont need loop remove loop and breaking variable and try again it should work

Comment: @Kael53 `System.in` is controlled by the Java runtime. You should never close it. What if he calls `getLogLocation()` again?

Comment: @Ben Get rid of `breaking` and just check `server == null`. You last issue is that you're *not* updating `choice` *inside the loop*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems in your code.

- in previous version you ware looping while there is next element, but for `System.in` we can't know if there is next element or not, because this stream is always opened, so there is a chance to get new data and method `hasNext` will wait for new data, or for signal of closing this stream
- in newer version of your code each time you invoke this method you are creating `Scanner` wrapping `System.in` and later you are closing it, which means you are also closing `System.in` and once it is closed you can't read from it again.

So instead of recreating Scanner each time, create it once and pass it to your method like

```
private static String getLogLocation(Scanner scanner){
    ...
    String data = scanner.readLine();
    ...
    //scanner.close(); //DON'T do it in this method!!!
}
```

Now about your loop, you can create something like:

```
Set<String> correctOptions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("opt1", "opt2"));// and so on
String option = null;
do {
    System.out.print("select option: ");
    option = scanner.nextLine();
} while (!correctOptions.contains(option));
//here you are sure that selected option is correct
//handle it as you want.
```

Comment: Since you're using `contains` you should make `correctOptions` a `Set`.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, using Set would be optimization if we would have many options, but in this scenario List is good enough.

Comment: True, but as the list grows, a Set becomes more important. Better get into the habit of using one for patterns like that, and you never have to rethink it.